# KeyError: u'FLASK_AUTH_REALM'

Tags: python, authentication, flask

I impemented today https://pypi.python.org/pypi/flask-htpasswd/ on my site and I'm getting KeyError: u'FLASK_AUTH_REALM' error. What I did was putting app.config's before Class so it looks like here:

```
from .utils import now, dottedQuadToNum, get_blacklist
log = logging.getLogger(__name__)
compress = Compress()
import flask
from flask_htpasswd import HtPasswdAuth

app = flask.Flask(__name__)
app.config['FLASK_HTPASSWD_PATH'] = 'C:/.htpasswd'
app.config['FLASK_SECRET'] = 'Hey Hey Kids, secure me!'
htpasswd = HtPasswdAuth(app)


class Pogom(Flask):

    def __init__(self, import_name, **kwargs):
```

And here's an error that I'm getting

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1997, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1985, in wsgi_app
    response = self.handle_exception(e)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1540, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1982, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1614, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1517, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1612, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1598, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\flask_htpasswd.py", line 205, in decorated
    return self.auth_failed()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\flask_htpasswd.py", line 159, in auth_failed
    current_app.config['FLASK_AUTH_REALM']
KeyError: u'FLASK_AUTH_REALM'
```

Comment: Have you tried setting the value manually? Default value for `'FLASK_AUTH_REALM'` should be `'Login Required'` (according to htpasswd source).

Comment: I did that, doesn't work either :/ "app.config['FLASK_AUTH_REALM'] = 'test'"

Comment: The KeyError mentions Unicode, try `[u'FLASK_AUTH_REALM']`

Answer (score 0):

You do not show the complete code. I guess you want to declare the `Pogom` class which derive from `Flask` class, then declare an instance from `Pogom`, and execute `pogom.run`.

According to the exception stack, I think missing `FLASK_AUTH_REALM` key in `app.config`.

Why the `FLASK_AUTH_REALM` missing?

First, the flask_htpasswd extension will set the default value for `FLASK_AUTH_REALM` in `init_app` function.

But you declare one new class, and may be instance one app from `Pogom` and `app.run`. the flask_htpasswd just initialize the old app which is the instance `Flask`, and the new app does not have proper `FLASK_AUTH_REALM` key in config.

So, I try to show some code like below:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_htpasswd import HtPasswdAuth


class Pogom(Flask):
    def __init__(self, import_name, **kwargs):
        # missing some special code
        super(Pogom, self).__init__(import_name, **kwargs)


htpasswd = HtPasswdAuth()


def create_app():
    app = Pogom(__name__)
    app.config['FLASK_HTPASSWD_PATH'] = 'C:/.htpasswd'
    app.config['FLASK_SECRET'] = 'Hey Hey Kids, secure me!'
    htpasswd.init_app(app)
    return app


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = create_app()

    # just for demonstration
    @app.route('/')
    @htpasswd.required
    def index():
        return "Hello"


    app.run()
```

Comment: I'm just a begginer in coding so I don't know how things work yet :D Thank you very much for help :)